# CMD Full Screen Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, command-line

I accidently made a command shell full screen, I managed to get it back to its original state but now when I run visual studio my screen flashes black, I assume this is the full screen command shell kickign in.

Can anyone help please?  If one more colleague asks do I have a virus I am going to headbut the desk.

Thanks,

B

Comment: Your colleagues are idiots (no offence intended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command prompt, from its system menu (click on icon at top left) select default and ensure full screen is not selected on the options tab.

Comment: If top left that is off screen use ALT-Space to access it.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution did not help me. Running cmd.exe no longer opens full screen, but running it from other locations (like visual studio does) still opens full screen. And the build goes too fast to change to options of the build prompt itself. So other ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Found solution after a lot of googling on microsoft.com: On Windows Server 2000, Windows XP (32-Bit), Windows Server 2003, and Windows Vista (32-Bit): Run Regedt32, which is located in the \System32 subfolder of the Windows NT root folder. Open the \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console branch of the registry tree. Set the FullScreen value to 0. Exit the registry editor. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126031/en-us?spid=3041&sid=global

(copied from comment)

Answer (score 1):

Alt + Enter, is the full screen toggle for the Command Prompt.