# Open a Console/Command Window when using VS 2008 Express

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

I have both the VB and C# versions of Visual Studio 2008 Express. When I run a console application in either version, instead of the console opening in an old DOS style command window like it does in VS 2005, it actually blacks out both monitors attached to my computer and treats the entire screen real estate as the console.

Anyone know how to get the app to run in a small command-type window when I run it?

**Update:**
It's like the console is running Full Screen.  If I set a break point, switch from the IDE t the console and then hit Alt+Enter it switches to the small window that I want, but I still can't figure out how to make the app start with the console that way.

I could post a screenshot but it would look like a big black square...no window, no frame, just the inky blackness of frustration.

Comment: A screenshot of what you are seeing will help.

Comment: he's seeing a maximized command prompt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Press your windows key + R to open a Run dialog. Type **cmd** and hit enter. This will open a command prompt. If it opens maximized, then un-maximize ("restore") it. Then close it. Now see if it starts maximized.

I think it's due to Windows saving the default size and placement of windows, and hopefully this will reset the default.

-Edit- Okay try this then: [CMD Full Screen Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626035/cmd-full-screen-visual-studio)

Comment: I wish it was that easy - win+r > cmd opened my nice, normal standard command window.  Closed VS Express and tried again - the console stayed full screen.  It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Perfect! That answer (Open a command prompt, from its system menu select default and then 'window' in the display options.) 

I had clicked through to the properties menu a dozen times, and missed that there was a 'defaults' menu each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Alt+Enter to get out of full screen mode.

Comment: That was what I was doing each time.  The question was how to make the app default to run in a window rather than full screen.